# bower not reading .bowerrc proxy settings (windows)

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, bower, bower-install

I'm working on a windows machine behind a corporate firewall. Sad, but true. Anyway, what I do to overcome this problem is to set environment variables from cmd level:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy-url
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy-url
```

and then bower works fine. But I do know that bower has the `.bowerrc` file ([specification](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md)) that includes `proxy` and `https-proxy` attributes. This is my .bowerrc content:

```
{
  "proxy": "http://proxy-url",
  "https-proxy": "http://proxy-url",
  "strict-ssl": false
}
```

I try to use bower using the `.bowerrc` file, which - I'm sure - is in the local directory I'm calling bower from. But then (having .bowerrc and not having env variables set) bower fails - it gets connection timeout.

I think I should not have to set the windows environment variables each time I open the console, since this is what the rc files are for. I know .rc files come from Unix, but bower should programatically handle them.

Am I doing something wrong - or did I misunderstand something here?

Comment: is your .bowerrc file placed in the root folder of your project? Did you try without strict-ssl? Do you need proxy credentials to log in to?

Comment: @LaurentH yes sir, `.bowerrc` is in main project dir. No, I don't need proxy credentials. I do need the ignore-ssl/strict-ssl: false because of network config (other things don't work as well).

Comment: Hm strange. Like you do in your .bowerrc, it should work...

Answer (score 1):

I've had a bad experience recently with a .bowerrc not behaving. We have legacy app which uses grunt-bower during the build. It seemed to randomly break the other day for my machine.

Putting `.bowerrc` into my home directory: `c:/users/USERNAME` and restarting `cmd` made it be respected in my case.

Comment: I don't know how long I was just searching for an answer why my .bowerrc-file had no impact on my installation. While on another project it worked perfectly your answer solved my problem. Thank you soo much for sharing your solution!